# Callstack not created in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, callstack

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<utility>
#define P(i, j) all[i-r0][j-c0]
#define C(i, j) check[i-r0][j-c0]

int r0, c0, r1, c1;
std::stack<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, int>> s;
std::vector<int> mov = {-1, 0, 1};

int move(std::vector<std::vector<bool>> all, std::vector<std::vector<bool>> check){
    auto p = s.top();
    if(p.first.first==r1&&p.first.second==c1)
        return p.second;
    while(!s.empty()){
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
                auto r = p;
                r.first.first += mov[i];
                r.first.second += mov[j];
                r.second++;
                if(r.first.first>=r0&&r.first.first<=r1&&r.first.second>=c0&&r.first.second<=c1&&P(r.first.first, r.first.second)&&!C(r.first.first, r.first.second)){
                    s.push(r);
                    C(r.first.first, r.first.second) = 1;
                    return move(all, check);
                }
            }
        s.pop();
    }
}

int main(){
    std::cin>>r0>>c0>>r1>>c1;
    s.push({{r0, c0}, 0});
    int n;  std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> all(r1-r0+1, std::vector<bool>(c1-c0+1));
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> check(r1-r0+1, std::vector<bool>(c1-c0+1));
    C(r0, c0)=1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int tempx;
        std::cin>>tempx;
        int tempy1, tempy2;
        std::cin>>tempy1>>tempy2;
        for(int j=tempy1; j<=tempy2; j++)
            if(j<=c1&&j>=c0&&tempx<=r1&&tempx>=r0)
                P(tempx, j) = 1;
    }
    std::cout<<move(all, check)<<'\n';
}
```

In the above program, when I provide the following inputs

```
5 7 6 11
3
5 3 8
6 7 11
5 2 5
```

and then use a debugger to analyze the code, its weird that on the 6th call, when the code reaches `return move(all, check)`, its not called and no stack for it is created. Instead its just skipped and `s.pop()` function is called sequentially. Is there any valid reason for this ?

Please use breakpoints at `return move(all, check)` and `s.pop()` if you are putting this on a debugger.

Comment: when you have terminal recursion like with `return move(all, check);` the compiler don't need to create a stack frame. because the variable from the calling function can't be used after the call.

Comment: Your function has undefined behavior because some routes don't return values.

Comment: VTT I know, but its perfectly valid for given inputs

Comment: It is not valid even if for given input `s.empty()` is false or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any valid reason for this ?

Yes, those reasons are **compiler optimizations**, specifically [**tail call optimization**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization). Compilers are allowed to generate whatever code they want as long as the *observable behavior* of your program doesn't change.

In this case, tail call optimization allows the compiler to eliminate the overhead of creating a new stack frame by just reusing the current one. Since your debugging sessions (and stack frames) are not considered part of observable behavior, it is fully within the compiler's rights to mess with the call stack like this.

A similar thing happens for inlined functions: You also don't get a new stack frame because the function call is replaced with the inlined code.

Most compilers will not do these optimizations in a debug build though. So if you prefer to debug with the "real" call stack, switch to a debug build (and hope that the bug still appears there).

Comment: but the observable behaviour is changing. I am not getting the desired output. When the function was supposed to recurse for one final time, its not called instead the next statement is executed

Comment: @GauravPant this is probably because of undefined behavior

Comment: @Tyker I checked on debugger. The program is reaching the function the 6th time, but its not executed

Comment: @GauravPant if you have undefined behavior anything can happend.

Comment: @Tyker, I know it sounds weird, but after changing the filename, the same code with given inputs works perfectly fine

Comment: @GauravPant Do you also get this issue in a debug build? The compiler should not do these kinds of optimizations there, so you should be able to, well, debug your problem. The "missing" stack frames are just one of many ways in which debugging optimized code is unintuitive, but is exceedingly unlikely to be the real issue.